# The following exception is caused by a lack of memory and not having swap configured in magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, database, ajax, sample-data

When trying to install the sample data via this command `php bin/magento sampledata:deploy` got an error

> The following exception is caused by a lack of memory and not having
>   swap configured.

Can you please help for the same?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server has a lack of memory (and not having swap configured) to work with composer.

Plese follow instruction [How to add swap](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-16-04) to resolve issue